# Валидация json в node js

Tags: json, node.js, валидация

Необходимо сделать валидацию json

Пример:

```
validate({username: "",id 0,roles: {blue: false,red: true}},{username: "uuuvn",id: 6,roles: {blue: true,red: false}});//true
validate({username: "",id 0,roles: {blue: false,red: true}},{username: "uuuvn",id: 6,roles: {blue: true,green: false}});//false
```

Comment: Неплохо бы понять что вы понимаете под словами json и валидация

Comment: То что вы показали, НЕ является JSON, ни первый, ни второй кейс. Причина: ознакомьтесь со [спецификацией JSON](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-12), должно быть `{"username": ...}`, у вас - `{username: ...}`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Comment: Я делал в спешке, у меня "username"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi)

```
const joi = require('@hapi/joi')
const schema = joi.object().keys({
    username: joi.string().required(),
    id: joi.number().integer().positive().required(),
    roles: joi.object().keys({
        blue: joi.boolean().required(),
        red: joi.boolean().required()
    }).required() 
})

function validate(object, schema){
    const {err, value} = schema.validate(object)
    if (err) return false;
    return true;
}

validate({username: "", id 6, roles: { blue: false, red: true }}, schema) //true
validate({username: "", id 6, roles: { blue: false, green: true }}, schema) //false
```